# How to generate text using list values generated by permutations

Tags: python, string, permutation

I have:

N = a list of numbers from 0-29

A = a list of all alphabet letters.

I want to combine them in order to get all possible permutations of "NAN", from 0a0 up to 29z29

Then, I want to use each one of these "NAN" permutations and get them inside a URL, so I can get something like
 "http://www.geo.ma/NAN.txt"

```
import string
import itertools

#Generate the letter list
Alist=list(string.ascii_lowercase)
#Generate the number list
Nlist=list(range(30))

#Combine them in order to get "ABA"
CombinedList=(list((itertools.product(Nlist, Alist, Nlist))))

print(CombinedList)
```

I got the list, but now I try to get the permutations inside the URL:

```
for i in CombinedList:
    print('http://www.geo.ma/', i)
```

But i get
`http://www.geo.ma/ (29, z, 29)`
instead of what I'd like to get:
`http://geo.ma/29z29.txt`

If I try to convert the List to string before trying to generate the URLS with `StringedList = str(CombinedList)`, python just uses each one of the characters to generate the URLs, so I get things like `http://geo.ma/].txt`, `http://geo.ma/9.txt`, `http://geo.ma/z.txt`, `http://geo.ma/).txt`, `http://geo.ma/).txt`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in CombinedList:
    print('http://www.geo.ma/'+str(i[0])+i[1]+str(i[2])+'.txt')
```

output is

```
http://www.geo.ma/0a0.txt
http://www.geo.ma/0a1.txt
http://www.geo.ma/0a2.txt
http://www.geo.ma/0a3.txt
http://www.geo.ma/0a4.txt
http://www.geo.ma/0a5.txt
http://www.geo.ma/0a6.txt
http://www.geo.ma/0a7.txt
http://www.geo.ma/0a8.txt
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
baseURL = "http://www.geo.ma/"
for pair in CombinedList:
    N1, A, N2 = pair
    print(f"{baseURL}{N1}{A}{N2}.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

use `.join()`

```
for i in CombinedList:
    print('http://www.geo.ma/{}'.format(''.join(map(str,i))))
```

output:

```
...

http://www.geo.ma/29z22
http://www.geo.ma/29z23
http://www.geo.ma/29z24
http://www.geo.ma/29z25
http://www.geo.ma/29z26
http://www.geo.ma/29z27
http://www.geo.ma/29z28
http://www.geo.ma/29z29
```